# Is there any difference between the phrase "all the better" and "so much the better"?

Tags: difference, adverbs, phrases

Is there any difference between the phrases? For example:

> If you can come earlier, it is **all the better**.
>
> If you can come earlier, **it is so much the better**.

By the way, do I have to include *it is*  as in *it is* all the better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

The difference is regional. I personally would only tend to say "all the better" as that is what was used most commonly around me when I was younger. However both phrases mean the same thing and can be used interchangeably.

> By the way do I have to include it is as in it is all the better?

Again no
It is perfectly acceptable to say:

> If *you* can come earlier, all the better
>
> If *you* can come earlier, so much the better

(Note: I've added in the word **you** to the sentences as it was missing.)